# What do "(מ)" and "(ש)" mean in an Israeli cryptic?

Tags: language, cryptic-crosswords

I was looking at the Hebrew cryptic crosswords in a recent copy of the Israel newspaper ידיעות אחרונות, and I noticed that some of the clues had "(מ)" or "(ש)" — or sometimes both — appended at the end, before the letter count. They seem to be information about the clue or perhaps about the answer (light) rather than part of the clue. There's a lot I don't know about Israeli cryptic-crossword conventions, but I figured I'll start with this: What do those two mean?

Comment: Mostly speculation (since I don't speak Hebrew), but I know that cryptics in English sometimes have similar things to indicate a particular dictionary as a reference for an uncommon word -- for instance, in [Run On by Ucaoimhu](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~wald/con15d.pdf), you can see the tag [NI2], indicating Webster's New International, second edition. [...]

Comment: [...] I've also seen similar tags for abbreviations, slang, and "foreign words" (as in [this noncryptic crossword in Indonesian](http://crosswordunclued.com/2016/02/a-crossword-in-bahasa-indonesia.html)). Not knowing any Hebrew, I can't say which of these (if any) is plausible, but maybe one jumps out to you, looking at the entries where the extra tags appear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ש' = שמיעה. ל' = לעז. ס' = סלנג. מ' = כתיב מלא.

**(ש) - Sound (the answer sounds alike to the words hinted at by the clue)**

Example: In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rPKpX6hSh0) they have "נשק בלתי קונבנציונלי הוא קטלני אבל אין מדובר בביולוגי" (*Unconventional weapon which is deadly but we're not speaking of biological*). The answer to that clue is אבא חורג (*Step father* / Pronouced: *Aba khoreg*) because it sounds like אב"כ הורג (*[Weapon of mass destruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_of_mass_destruction)* / Pronouced: *Abakh horeg*).

**(ל) - Foreign word**

**(ס) - Slang**

**(מ) - Plene spelling**

---

Sources:

- [http://ezori.net/articles/תרבות-ופנאי/5168/](http://ezori.net/articles/%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%99/5168/)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rPKpX6hSh0

Comment: +1, and many thanks!

Comment: @msh210 No problem. Hebrew crosswords are not one of my skills, but Googling is something I've gotten pretty good at and I know a little Hebrew.

Comment: @DenverCoder1 Could you please spell it out (transliterate) in English and give an English translation of the clue?

Comment: @Scratch---Cat My translation may not be perfect since I am not a native speaker, but I have attempted it.